# Removing or hiding values in a cell

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtable

Is there a way to hide or remove value of a certain cell or whole column?
If you take a look at this photo:

[image: Table image]

you will see that I am very creative when it comes to adding mock data to a table.

All jokes aside, I want to remove all values from Priority column, so there are only colored cells. Is it possible? Maybe iterate through the whole column and set values to null? Just an idea without a realization plan...

**EDIT**

My cell renderer:

```
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
        int row, int column) {
    Component cell = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

    if(value.equals("1")) { // red
        cell.setBackground(Color.RED);
        cell.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    } else if (value.equals("2")) { // yellow
        cell.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        cell.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    } else if (value.equals("3")) { // green
        cell.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        cell.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    } else { // white
        cell.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        cell.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Assigning renderer to the table:

```
TableColumn tblColumn = this.tblTodo.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
    tblColumn.setCellRenderer(new PriorityColumnCellRenderer());
```

Comment: Why not just set the renderer to display exactly what you want it to display?

Comment: That could be a way to go, but how? I edited my post with the code

Comment: You could set `value = ""` in your cell when you call the super's method.

Comment: `Component cell = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, "", isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply change the value of `value` in your super method call within renderer's `getTableCellRendererComponent(...)` method to be an empty String: `""`:

```
Component cell = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, "", isSelected, 
        hasFocus, row, column);
```

e.g.,

```
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
        int row, int column) {
    Component cell = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, "", isSelected, 
        hasFocus, row, column);

    if(value.equals("1")) { // red
        cell.setBackground(Color.RED);
        cell.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    } else if (value.equals("2")) { // yellow
        cell.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        cell.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    } else if (value.equals("3")) { // green
        cell.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        cell.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    } else { // white
        cell.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        cell.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Sure, thanks. In my case this needs to be done separately after checking the value, as I wrote in my answer

Comment: @SebastianDudas: no it doesn't. Please see renderer code above. Keep it simple as possible.

Comment: Oh, that is the case... Didn't realize that is the new object. That is fixed, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer.

There is a method in super's class:

```
super.setValue("myValue");
```

In my case, this will look like this:

```
super.setValue(null);
```

But this needs to be called after checking the value. Final code:

**EDIT**

```
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
        int row, int column) {
    Component cell = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

    if(value.equals("1")) { // red
        cell.setBackground(Color.RED);
        cell.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        super.setValue(null);
    } else if (value.equals("2")) { // yellow
        cell.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        cell.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        super.setValue(null);
    } else if (value.equals("3")) { // green
        cell.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        cell.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        super.setValue(null);
    } else { // white
        cell.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        cell.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
        super.setValue(null);
    }

    return cell;
}
```

**EDIT**

To keep it simple, I used [Hovercraft Full Of Eels](https://stackoverflow.com/users/522444/hovercraft-full-of-eels)'s answer

Comment: I would only do this within the renderer as per my answer.

Comment: Yeah, it was in the renderer, code is now fully displayed. Thanks